Compare via \ifnum in TikZ to determine node content
In the following source, I'd like the test with \ifnum to display n instead of 4.75 corresponding to the value 4.75 of \x. How should this be done?
  \documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  
  \begin{document}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  
    \foreach \x in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4.75} {
        \filldraw (\x,0) circle (1pt);
        \node[anchor=south] at (\x,-0.5) {\ifnum 475=100*\x {$n$}\else {$\x$} \fi};
    };
    % want effect of following line to be accomplished via the test above
    % \node[anchor=south] at (4.75,-0.5) {$n$}; 
    \node[anchor=south] at (3.875,-0.5) {$\dotsb$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
  \end{document}



The conditional \ifnum only compares integers. However, it will perform macro expansion in order to determine what integers to compare, so you can use \fpeval.
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4.75} {
    \filldraw (\x,0) circle (1pt);
    \node[anchor=south] at (\x,-0.5) {\ifnum 475=\fpeval{100*\x}{$n$}\else {$\x$}\fi};
  }
  \node[anchor=south] at (3.875,-0.5) {$\dotsb$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Or you can directly use floating point number comparison.
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpcompareTF}{mmm}
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4.75} {
    \filldraw (\x,0) circle (1pt);
    \node[anchor=south] at (\x,-0.5) {\fpcompareTF{4.75=\x}{$n$}{$\x$}};
  }
  \node[anchor=south] at (3.875,-0.5) {$\dotsb$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

On the other hand, doing it separately seems easier.
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0, 1, 2, 3} {
    \filldraw (\x,0) circle (1pt);
    \node[anchor=south] at (\x,-0.5) {$\x$};
  }
  \filldraw (4.75,0) circle (1pt);
  \node[anchor=south] at (4.75,-0.5) {$n$};
  \node[anchor=south] at (3.875,-0.5) {$\dotsb$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

By the way, you shouldn't add ; after the closing brace for \foreach.

Since \ifnum wants to compare integers, why don't you just use an \ifx instead?
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\myval{4.75}
\begin{document}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}
  
  \foreach \x in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4.75} {
      \filldraw (\x,0) circle (1pt);
      \node[anchor=south] at (\x,-0.5) {\ifx\x\myval {$n$}\else {$\x$} \fi};
  };
  % want effect of following line to be accomplished via the test above
  % \node[anchor=south] at (4.75,-0.5) {$n$}; 
  \node[anchor=south] at (3.875,-0.5) {$\dotsb$};
\end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{document}



Why can't I directly put 4.75  instead of \myval, that is, why does it not work if I use instead this direct test: \ifx \x {4.75} ?

@murray \ifx \x { compares \x to { and it is false.  \ifx will be many hunfreds of times faster than fpeval here although that may not matter

In OpTeX, you can use \ismacro\x{4.75}\iftrue or \ifnum 475=\expr[0]{100*\x}.
\load[tikz]

\tikzpicture
  \foreach \x in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4.75} {
    \filldraw (\x,0) circle (1pt);
    \node[anchor=south] at (\x,-0.5) {\ismacro\x{4.75}\iftrue $n$\else $\x$\fi};
  }
  \node[anchor=south] at (3.875,-0.5) {$\dots$};
\endtikzpicture

\bye


I'm using pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX.
